# Dataset.WriteXml() namespace and prefix

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I have a DataSet with data that I output (write) to an XMl file.

I have added a namespace and prefix to the dataset like this:

```
public static string XmlNamespace = "http://namespace";
public static string XmlPrefix = "ns0";
RequestDataSet.Namespace = XmlNamespace;
RequestDataSet.Prefix = XmlPrefix;
```

The XML output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ns0:list xmlns:ns0="http://namespace">
  <ns0:item xmlns="http://namespace">
    <data1>1234</data1>
    <data2>91011</data2>
  </item>
</ns0:list>
```

But it should be like this: (no namespace on the item records. Just the prefix)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ns0:list xmlns:ns0="http://namespace">
  <ns0:item>
    <data1>1234</data1>
    <data2>91011</data2>
  </item>
</ns0:list>
```

I have tried setting the tables prefix/namespace to null like this:

```
RequestDataSet.Tables["item"].Prefix = XmlPrefix;
RequestDataSet.Tables["item"].Namespace = null;
```

But that also does not work... Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across similar issues when fighting with BizTalk adapters... but that's a different story.

Not sure if there is a different (cleaner) way, but you could always 'grab' the attribute and remove it, as decribed [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1463402.aspx/1).

Effectively you would do the following:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    if (xDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Count > 0)
    {
        XmlAttribute xAtt = xDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes[0];
        xDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Remove(xAtt);
```

Comment: Possible performance considerations here as well, depending on the size of your XML.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a different story, as the xml file i am building will get sent to a BizTalk server for processing, my problem is BizTalk not being able to validate my xml file because it doesn't like the namespace :) I am gonna try out the solution you gave me now! ill report back soon :)

Comment: Ah, BizTalk does seem to crop up in these scenarios! Ok, let me know. The solution we had in BizTalk was to have an inline funciton in the mapper which if I recall correctly did a similar thing to the above. There are potentially ways to fix this with XSLT in the mapper if that's an option for you. Keep me posted.

Comment: I could not get it done using the code you described above. The reason might be that i'm trying to accomplish this on item-elements level (too deep?) I am now using this (dirty solution?): 
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement; 
            root.InnerXml = root.InnerXml.Replace("xmlns=\"http://namespace\"", ""); From what I could find on the internet I don't think one should remove the xmlns element....

Comment: As I am under the impression that a non xmlns attribute would be removable using your solution ill give you credits for the answer :)

Comment: Thanks Phillip. Let me know how it goes. If you'd like a hand approaching things via BizTalk mapping and XSLT, give me a shout.

Comment: I eventualy went for a solution where I would use the WriteXml method, saving the file. And then opening it again for a replace loop that replaces the xmlns line with "" :)